# How to rollback in Google Code

Tags: svn, ankhsvn, google-code

I have a project hosted in Google Code. 
I'm working on Visual Studio with AnkSvn.

I accidently deleted a file and committed.

Although, Of cause, I can download the copy of the deleted file from code history, I think a rollback is a better idea.

Or in other words, I want my project to go back to r22 while the latest(corrupted) version has gone to r24.

I'm not familiar with either SVN or Google Code, so how can I perform a rollback? Or an suggestion on using SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Solution History, by right-clicking the solution in the solution explorer. Select "View Solution History" from the context menu.

Here you can right-click svn revisions and roll back to that revision, or undo a specific revision. So in your case either select r23 and r24 and use "revert changes from this revision", or right-click r22 and select "revert to this revision"

Comment: Yes, this gives me a direction. After doing what you say, I see the icon of the corrupted file becomes red square. Then I commit, it says my version is out of date, need update first. After I update, the icon shows a conflict of the file. I right-click the file, select Resolve and keey my file.Then I commit again, success now!

Answer (score 0):

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo for how to do it with the svn command line:

> An extremely common use for svn merge is to roll back a change that
>   has already been committed. Suppose you're working away happily on a
>   working copy of /calc/trunk, and you discover that the change made way
>   back in revision 303, which changed integer.c, is completely wrong. It
>   never should have been committed. You can use svn merge to “undo” the
>   change in your working copy, and then commit the local modification to
>   the repository. All you need to do is to specify a reverse difference.
>   (You can do this by specifying --revision 303:302, or by an equivalent
>   --change -303.)

I don't know about Ankhsvn, but in Tortoisesvn, you may show the log of a given directory or file, select one of the revision, right-click and select *Revert to this revision* or *Revert changes done in this revision*. Maybe something similar exists in Ankhsvn.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to undo the deletion of a single file, but keep the rest of the commit, you can yous `svn cp -R<Revisionnumber before the file was deleted> <URL of the file> .` to resurrect the file. This creates a History preserving "copy" of the deleted file into the working copy.

Since I don't know AnkSvn I describe the Tortoise-SVN way to create such a copy with GUI tools, and hope that AnkSvn does act in a similar way.

You open the repository explorer, and then select the revision before the deletion (search for a button to select the displayed revision there). then you copy the file out from the repository into your working copy (in TortoiseSVN this works by an right mouse button drag).